# jQuery selecting with an extra hash

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the parent of an id with an extra # in front of it, but it isn't working.  =
Does the '#' cause this to malfunction?  Or is there something wrong with the jQuery?

HTML:

```
<li><a href="blah" id="#id"></a></li>
<button id="clickme">click it</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  ('##id').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`.

[So `$('#\\#id')` should work](http://jsfiddle.net/3RZ8d/), though I really recommend to not use `#` as part of the ID, to avoid any possible problems. For example, I don't think there is away to escape the character in CSS rules (I could be wrong though) or using the ID as target (like `<a href="##id"></a>`) will probably not work either.

Comment: Didn't know this, but I had an inkling this was the issue.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a bad idea with special characters in selectors, but you can always just escape them :

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#\\#id').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/S5Taa/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/exngF/

You need to escape that extra `#`

```
$('#\\#id')
```

more info here

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

> In order to tell jQuery to treat these characters literally rather
>   than as CSS notation, they must be "escaped" by placing two
>   backslashes in front of them

Answer (score -1):

`#` is a special symbol reserved for `id`s. You shouldn't use it in the name of the id. Is there a specific reason why you would want to do this?

Comment: Not really an answer.. you can escape it using ` \\ `

Comment: Just because you can get around the issue by escaping the `#` doesn't mean you should. The better solution is to change the ID of parent div to something more palatable.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

You really should not have an element with the ID `#id`. Yes, you can get around the parsing issue by escaping the extra hash as others have suggested, but a better solution would be to give the parent div a better ID, one that doesn't require special handling.

Comment: True of HTML 4 but allowed in HTML5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: I still say it isn't a very good idea. The version of HTML hasn't been specified, nor has the OP provided an extenuating circumstance for why the ID can't be changed.

Comment: Subjective. Might make sense for some people and there coding practices. Though I won't do it myself